# Exception in thread "main" com.android.apksig.apk.MinSdkVersionException

Tags: cicd

The below code is in my YML file.

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  displayName: Signing the AAB file
  inputs:
  apkFiles: '**/*.aab'
  apksignerKeystoreFile: '**********'
  apksignerKeystorePassword:$(APK_SIGNER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)
  apksignerKeystoreAlias: $(APK_SIGNER_KEYSTORE_ALIAS)
  apksignerKeyPassword: $(APK_SIGNER_KEY_PASSWORD)

> Trying to create sign bundle Received below error :
> Caused by: com.android.apksig.apk.MinSdkVersionException: Failed to determine APK's minimum supported Android platform version
> Caused by: com.android.apksig.apk.ApkFormatException: Missing AndroidManifest.xml